# How to configure AWS UBUNTU Server to access html via server IP address

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So this post is not boring it is interesting, I am getting into AI cryptocurrency trading, there is only one open source platform that allows artificial intelligence to trade on my behalf, one method is run my own PC or use EC2 AWS.

For more History about GEKKO AI and server configuration go here:
https://gekko.wizb.it/docs/installation/configuring_gekko_on_a_server.html

Long story Short I have installed GEKKO AI on my EC2 Server, now the server is successfully running the AI but the User interface is not visible by browsing to the assigned server IP

Message From Putty Terminal says AI is successfully running on 3.85.36.175:3000

AI user interface address is  **3.85.36.175:3000** 
Error Message on the browser: **Site Refused to Connect**

The following java script CODE should create a User interface on the following IP ADDRESS:

```
const CONFIG = {
    headless: true,
    api: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
    },
    ui: {
        ssl: false,
        host: '3.85.36.175', // Set this to the IP of the machine that will run Gekko
        port: 3000,
        path: '/'
    },
    adapter: 'sqlite'

}

if(typeof window === 'undefined')
  module.exports = CONFIG;
else
  window.CONFIG = CONFIG;
```

In order to successfully view the AI user interface, I have to correctly configure the IP address. 
The EC2 is running Ubuntu server, and I have installed Node js GIT and GEKKO to install the GEKKO AI.
Since this is an opensource project no one is available as to why the server IP address is not showing the USER INTERFACE

Exactly Same issue Broadly Discussed on HERE but no concrete solution:
https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/2195

Comment: Did you set up the security rules for the EC2 instance to allow incoming traffic on port 3000?

Comment: yes I did these are security group settings

HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
HTTP
TCP
80
::/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
3000 - 3002
0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
3000 - 3002
::/0
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
SSH
TCP
22
::/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
::/0

Comment: the Terminal says that it is running GEKKO at this address
Serving Gekko UI on http://3.85.36.175:3000/

Comment: I must be missing one basic server configuration, I dont know what that is, tried various EC2 instance with Nginx , ubuntu, Ubuntu+nodejs nothing seem to work! 
What is causing the refusal to connect to  3.85.36.175:3000 , the AI is running, aslo I have created security groubs to allow both http https and port 3000 what is causing the html file to not get activated to that link i have not idea! what measures I can take

Comment: EXACT SAME ISSUE faced by another user with more details but no solution
https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/2195

Comment: If no solution is found soon I will have to BUY it from them at a very high price :( so trying to configure the AI before its too late :(